# Read a .java file from another class and call its method

Tags: java, file-read

Is it possible that to read a `.java` file as a file (using file path)from another class and call its method in this class ?

Lets takes a java class as

```
public Mylogic {

public static void test()

{
 //some logic

}

}
```

Is there a way another java class can read `Mylogic.java` file as a file and execute `test()` method
?

Why I want this?

Once `source code` goes into application server , then if I have to add another class , I have to wait for complete deployment which takes time.If I am able to do this, I can keep a `utility class` ready in `source code` to read `.java` file from dir and execute it without any deployment, thus saving time.
This is for higher environment (production mode) so no exploded mode.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from instantiating the `Mylogic` class and then using the resulting object?  Can you add some more background about what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: test is static method. We dont need instance of Mylogic class. And livinggourmand, are you trying to understand static methods of a class? If then yes, Any class can invoke a public static method which is declared in another class, which is public, as in your example: Mylogic. I guess, you meant by reading a file and executing - you actually meant, invoking test() method directly without instantiating Mylogic class?

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity In order to make the static call he stills needs to have the same setup which would allow for instantiation, e.g. bringing the class into his classpath and building appropriately.

Comment: @Tim I have added more details

Comment: @livinggourmand:  Based on the added details, my assumptions as stated above are wrong.

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity does my question makes sense  now ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you have JDK instead of JRE when running the code, using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` and a customized class loader:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;


public class LoadAndRun extends ClassLoader {

    public Class findClass(String name) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("./" + name + ".class");

            byte [] buff = new byte[4096];
            while (true) {
                int c = in.read(buff);
                if (c == -1) break;
                out.write(buff, 0, c);
            }

            return defineClass(name, out.toByteArray(), 0, out.toByteArray().length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
        // Try to get the system compiler
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        if (compiler == null) {
            System.err.println("System java compiler not found.");
            return;
        }

        // Prepare the java file to be compiled
        String classname = "LoadAndRun" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        File javaFile = new File(classname + ".java");

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(javaFile)));
        writer.write("public class " + classname + "{\n");
        writer.write("public static void test() {System.out.println(\"this is the test class:\"+"+classname+".class);}");
        writer.write("}\n");
        writer.close();

        // Compile it!
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(javaFile)).call();

        // Load and invoke static method
        ClassLoader classLoader = new LoadAndRun();
        Class cls = classLoader.loadClass(classname);
        Method m = cls.getMethod("test");
        m.invoke(null);

        // Clean up
        m = null;
        cls = null;
        classLoader = null;

        System.gc();

        javaFile.delete();
        File classFile = new File(classname + ".class");
        classFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I made changes to eclipse to use jdk1.8.0_25 and relaunched eclipse by `eclipsec.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe"` but it is still picking `jre7\bin\javaw.exe`.